# Fill values in a matrix from column 4 based on a value in column 3 for all categories in column 1 and column 2 in R

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate, xtabs

Dataframe df is the given dataframe and we want to obtain the matrix below for value in VAR3 as "101". Use of `xtabs()` does not produce the desired output. The value inside 2X2 matrix is the value in VAR4.

```
df <- data.frame(
  VAR1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  VAR2 = c(10,10,10,20,20,20,10,10,10,20,20,20),
  VAR3 = c(101,102,103,104,105,106,101,102,103,104,105,106),
  VAR4 = c(58,20,27,200,23,36,108,800,56,72,27,235)
)
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: Working backwards from your desired result, maybe `xtabs(VAR4 ~ VAR1 + VAR2, df, subset = VAR3 %in% c(101, 104))`.  Not clear as you don't mention needing to subset on `104`, just `101`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I want to subset on just 101